# Hide blank or zero priced prducts after import

Tags: php, woocommerce, catalog

I have a WooCommerce with automatic products import from a source and I have 2 different files to import: first one is for products, second one for prices and stocks.

Sometimes I import products that are still not present in the second file, and I get a list of "blank" price products that goes online on my shop.

How can I tell WooCommerce to not show those products?

Comment: I am playing with add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_is_visible'
but I cannot get what I want...

Comment: for the records: I did this

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_status = 'draft' WHERE ID IN (SELECT post_id  FROM `wp_postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_price' AND `meta_value` = '') AND post_status = 'publish'